# Will springboot 2.X use jetty10.x?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have saw that jetty9.x is EOL[1]. I want to know if springboot2.x will upgrade to jetty10.x?
Thanks for your reply.

[1] https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spring-boot-starter-jetty can be used with Jetty 10 but it still defaults to 9.4.x

The reason is probably that they are working on Spring Boot 3 which must support Jetty 11 because of the changed namespaces in Jakarta EE.

Check out also: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24886